# Gradient not working in Firefox – do I need specific color order?

Tags: firefox, css

If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/q2cFb/1/, you can see that both `#b` and `#a` is not working on  Firefox (13.0.1). Why is that? It works on Chrome (with different syntax, but same colors).

Do I need to have some specific colors for gradient to work? Both `#a` and `#c` are using two colors, but `#a` isn't working.

HTML:

```
<div id='c'></div>
<div id='b'></div>
<div id='a'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#c {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #131315 37%, #272727 75%);
}

#b {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #242424 80%, #1E1E1E 58%, #191919 20%);
}

#a {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #242424 80%, #191919 20%);
}
```

Comment: my suggestion. make it by Photoshop for best cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your percentages aren't in increasing order. See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient):

> Color-stops must be specified in order.

Answer (score 1):

try [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) it automatically does the css gradient coding for you.

example format for gradient for multibrowser

`background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */`